# Why does Xcode tell me 'stringValue' or 'text' cannot be used on type 'NSSearchField'?

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nssearchfield

I'm actually Swift Developer with main emphasis in UIKit and not AppKit or Cocoa. 
So Xcode tells me NSSearchField.stringValue? nor NSSearchField.text? is working, is that true? and if so, what should I use instead?

```
extension MapViewController: NSSearchFieldDelegate {
        override func searchFieldAction(sender: NSSearchField) 
            defer {
            }

            guard let text = NSSearchField.stringValue?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
                where !text.isEmpty else { return }

            let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
            request.naturalLanguageQuery = text
            request.region = mapView.region

            let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
            search.startWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) in
                guard let item = response?.mapItems.first else { return }

                let annotation = item.placemark
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
                self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

Comment: How about `sender.stringValue`?  It's not a class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSSearchField` is the class. `sender` is an *instance* of `NSSearchField`.

You want to use the *instance* of the class `sender.stringValue`

Comment: did that, but Xcode now tells me "Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not 'string'" which makes sense but how should I do that?

Comment: Hi @IliasMay. Is that on the `guard let text` line?  I don't think `stringValue` is optional, it's always a string.  I haven't tried it but something like this should work:

`let text = sender.stringValue.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet());

if text.isEmpty { return }`